# wxWindows 2.9 binary for windows

Tags: wxwidgets, wxhaskell

After an upgrade to the new Haskell Platform, my existing wxHaskell programs are broken.
They all seem to now require wxWidgets 2.9, for which I can't find any binary versions.
wxPack has 2.8, and beyond that one has to get a compiler and build it locally from what I see.

There are tutorials on this from various sources, each a few pages long, with various advice on setup, changing configurations, etc. Install wxConfig, install minGW compilers, setup configurations, rebuild, etc.

Is there any source of a simple binary install? I'd hope for some simple *apt-get* or *cabal* like tool, Haskell library tools (on Windows?) seem less integrated than others that I'm familiar with.

(Update) I did install and compile wxWidgets locally, and still cannot get the wxHaskell components to install. I'm sure that all of this just requires some fairly simple details, but again after some time already, hope not to have to spend a lot more time on this, and wish it was more automated!

```
Configuring wxc-0.90.0.3...
Configuring wxc to build against wxWidgets 2.9

setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
* Missing C libraries: wxmsw29ud_all, wxtiffd, wxjpegd, wxpngd, wxzlibd,
wxregexud, wxexpatd, wxregexud
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wx-0.90.0.1 depends on wxc-0.90.0.3 which failed to install.
wxc-0.90.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was: ExitFailure 1
wxcore-0.90.0.1 depends on wxc-0.90.0.3 which failed to install.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. CodeLite (C++ IDE I use) was recently upgraded to use wx29.
Since there are no binaries yet on repo, Dave set up some. Find all instruction in CodeLite's wiki below

[wxWidgets 2.9 Packages and Repositories](http://www.codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets29Binaries)

If you are using windows Just go to download page for Codelite and download codelite with wxWidgets. Install it, copy the installed wxWidgets directory wherever it is needed!

Also it seems like there are official binaries. I have never tested download anything there so try yourself. The link is [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/2.9.4/binaries/)

Feel free to ask any question

Comment: Thanks - I should have clarified, I am on Windows-7, any binaries for that?